# validation an expression tree

Tags: c++, binary-tree

I've almost got my validation function to work, but I just wrote the last part where it checks the internal nodes to make sure they're opperators. Without this part, the function checks the leaf nodes fine. Though, when I include the internal part, it prints out the first node "-" and returns false.

```
bool validate(tnode* node)
{  
  cout<<"validating leaf nodes...."<<endl;
  if(node == NULL)
  {
    cout<<"Node is null";       
    return false;
  }
  if(node->left != NULL || node->right != NULL )
  {
        cout<<node->key<<endl<<endl;
        if(node->key != '+' || node->key != '-' || node->key != '/'  || node->key != '*')
            return false;
  }  
  if(node->left == NULL && node->right==NULL) 
  {
    cout<<"Found leave node "<<node->key<<endl<<endl;
    if(node->key == '+' || node->key == '-' || node->key == '*' || node->key == '/')
        return false;
  }   
  else
    return validate(node->left) && validate(node->right); 
}
```

The problem code with this function is..

```
if(node->left != NULL || node->right != NULL )
  {
        cout<<node->key<<endl<<endl;
        if(node->key != '+' || node->key != '-' || node->key != '/'  || node->key           != '*')
            return false;
  }
```

Without it, the function works perfectly! Any ideas what is causing it?

Comment: What happens if `node` is equal to NULL?

Comment: Did you want to change your ORs to ANDs, e.g. || to && ?

Answer (score 1):

The expression of the `if` statement breaks your program because it causes the function to prematurely stop validating nodes. If either the `left` or `right` node is set it checks for an operator and if it finds one it returns `true`. If a match is found it prevents further validation from happening if  `left`, `right` or both point to more nodes. If you replace the logical *or* operator with a logical *and* operator the code can still fail because the expression checking for operators is totally **whack**. In order for that block of code to work it would need to be changed to something like this:

```
if(node->left == NULL && node->right == NULL )
{
    cout<<node->key<<endl<<endl;

    if(node->key == '+' || node->key == '-'
       || node->key == '/'  || node->key == '*')
        return true;

    // nothing else to check since both left and right are null
    return false;
 }
```

You have also over complicated your solution and duplicated code. Since the current node is valid you only have to check the key it stores for operators. In this case you can simply call `validate` for both the left and right nodes if they are not null and only check the current nodes key. The code below is untested but looks correct.

```
bool validate(tnode* node)
{  
    cout << "validating leaf nodes...." << endl;

    // Invalid node. 
    if(node == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Node is null";       
        return false;
    }

    // We have a left node, go validate it.
    if(node->left != NULL)
    {
        return validate(node->left);
    }

    // We have a right node, go validate it.
    if(node->right != NULL)
    {
        return validate(node->right);
    }

    // Now let's check the key.
    cout  <<  "Found leaf node " << node->key << endl << endl;

    if(node->key == '+' || node->key == '-'
       || node->key == '/'  || node->key == '*')
    {
        // BOOYAH!
        cout << "Operator: " << node->key << endl << endl;
        return true;
    }  


    // This isn't the key type we're looking for.
    return false;
}
```

I also recommend making `validate` a const qualified member function of `tnode`, this *is* C++ afterall.